Jellyfin on WSL - relative link defined for config, WSL/DD put it somewhere else, contents lost in symlink hell
I recently migrated Jellyfin from Ubuntu to Docker Desktop/WSL. My media is on networked shares and those work fine. I also copied in my config folder to the machine, making what I now know was a terrible mistake. I mounted with a relational link in Docker Compose as follows:
volumes:
 - /home/jellyfin-data/config:/config

Those of you who have played in WSL probably know where this is going, but I didn't until later. Jellyfin acted like it was a fresh install (which I shrugged off as the price of changing platforms and diligently worked for days cleaning up various bits of metadata). But it accepted the mount link just fine, so it wasn't until I went fishing for logs in the bowels of Docker Desktop that I discovered it had created a whole new file store for config...somewhere. I only know that it isn't where I put the old files because those aren't changing, and new files, like new logs, are absent.
I can see the files in Docker Desktop - Containers - container - Files. I can even download them (but not fully with the container running, and that avenue isn't available with the container stopped). Docker Desktop sincerely believes the files are in /home/jellyfin-data/config, it doesn't know its links are altered upstream. And although it has a clickable link, the link doesn't actually open anything (like, anything, not even a 404 or error, nothing happens at all).
Screenshot of Docker Desktop thinking it knows where my files are
Screenshot of Docker Desktop with my files somewhere, but not where it seemed
My goal here is to download the contents of config for backup and to ideally re-create the container with the contents somewhere I actually can access them (so, if I were doing it today instead of last week, I'd have known to manually create the volume first, which goes into a location I can find). Theoretically downloading it from inside Docker Desktop should do it, but that's not an available option with the container off and the database doesn't copy with it running. Portainer does show volumes not in use but doesn't seem to have an option to go into the contents.
I also wonder if there is a CLI option to stop the database or service without stopping the container that might allow me to get it out via Docker Desktop. That could get me where I need to go even if I never actually find the files.
I have searched manually where Docker Desktop puts its own new volumes, which it calls /var/lib/docker/volumes (reached from Windows at \wsl.localhost\docker-desktop\mnt\docker-desktop-disk\data\docker\volumes) and various folders above and below.
I have tried to run locate searches for jellyfin.db in the WSL CLI. However, the initial updatedb build seems to choke on the looping symlinks and the permission-denied Windows directories and eventually seems to stall.
I have run searches from Windows Explorer, to no avail, but have since found out that Linux symlinks don't consistently (or ever?) show up in Windows, so that's not surprising.
I'm out of ideas, other than eating a few days of manual metadata and config work and rebuilding fresh. Which, to be honest, I'm likely to kick down the road until I'm forced to do it by a machine crash. But I'm really, really hoping someone else has done this and just knows where to look!
